# sqlite: How can I check with PHP if a Record already exists?

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to use PHP to check if a database entry (SQLlight) already exists.

I fetch the DB Records first:

```
$db->exec("SELECT * FROM $tbMgmt WHERE resourceId LIKE '$resourceId' AND EventType Like '$EventType'");
```

When the Result is `0`, I want to proceed with my Script. if the Result is `1` or higher, I want to stop:

```
if ($db) {

    echo "Record already exists!";
} else {

 // proceed with my Script ...
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of rows returned from your query;

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $tbMgmt WHERE resourceId LIKE '$resourceId' AND EventType Like '$EventType'");
$count = $result->rowCount(); 

if($count == 0){
    // proceed with Script ...
}
```

Comment: rowCount will not work and will throw an error.